# Wordpress Restful Api without html tags

Tags: json, rest, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have the `JSON API` plugin installed on my WordPress installation, when I output my `RESTFUL API`, there are `<p>` tags and other html  in there for example, in my app it will:

A line will say `<p>Hello World</p>` not Hello world (without html tags)

Does anyone know why and how this can be fixed? Thanks

Comment: That's not how the API works...The content field is a string exactly how it appears in the database. You'll either need to store the content in a different field without HTML tags, or strip them after you retrieve the data from the API.

Comment: what would you recommend?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to remove the html tags @Sole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try removing the filter `wpautop` from the content on your site. -- This is assuming that "Hello World" is a part of the content, and that you don't mind removing the `<p>` tags from everywhere that the content is served.

```
remove_filter ('the_content',  'wpautop');
```

Here is some more documentation on `wpautop` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop